# Assigning a static IP to Ubuntu Server 14.04 to access ownCloud out of the server

Tags: dns, dhcp, static-ip, owncloud-server

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I did this steps recently, with 'AskUbuntu' support:
- installation of Ubuntu, ownCloud server + client, Oracle VirtualMachine
- configured ddns (duckdns.org)
- port forward, necessary for the ddns work properly.

I can access Owncloud from other machines, using my local network.
But I can't access my owncloud server when I'm outside of my local network.
I'm using wired network at home, where the Ubuntu machine is installed.

Talking to a friend I realized that I need to set up a static IP to make the DDNS work properly and, then, have access to ownCloud from outside my local network.
I searched the documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Then, I followed all the advices and changed the files
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/hosts

I used my address, netmask and gateway.
I'm sure the numbers used to address, netmask and gateway are correct.
I used 'ifconfig' and route -n to check it.

I also restarted the network, shutting down the system.
After start the machine again, the wired network doesn't work.

Please help me to find where is my mistake.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's hard to guess unless you include the contents of those files - or at least a clearer definition of "doesn't work" (interface doesn't come up? doesn't accept incoming traffic? doesn't route outgoing traffic? doesn't resolve names?)

Comment: Editing the files you described only changes things for the machine on which you've made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order for machines outside of your LAN (ie: The Internet, WAN) to have access to a machine inside of your LAN, you'll need a few things.

1. The WAN IP for your Network
2. A NAT-capable Router/Gateway
3. Port-Forwarding from the WAN IP:PORT to the LAN IP:PORT

#### WAN IP

You can set up a true DNS solution if your IP doesn't change.  Another option would be to look into *dynamic dns* providers.

Depending on your Router/Gateway, you may have settings to automatically update different dynamic dns providers with your new IP if it changes.  I would recommend using one of these services if your Router/Gateway supports it.  One such Router/Gateway firmware that supports dynamic dns is DD-WRT.

#### NAT

This just means you need to have a Router/Gateway that allows multiple clients to connect to it and share the Internet connection.  This is a typical setup, but thought it was worth mentioning.

#### Port Forwarding

You will be connecting to ownCloud through ports 80 or 443 (TCP).  This is http:// or https://, so it is highly recommended that you connect and force connections through https.

Your Router/Gateway needs to be set up so that it forwards all connections from its WAN IP:PORT to your machine's LAN IP:PORT.

On the machine running ownCloud, you can run `ifconfig` to determine your IP.  Go to your Router/Gateway configuration and ensure these ports are forwarded.

Comment: Thanks! My WAN IP is dynamic and I'm using DuckDNS as provider for dynamic dns. My router allows multiple clients and the port forwarding is OK using a http:// for a while. I will configure the https:// as soon as solve the problem I mentioned here.

Comment: Nice.  Do you understand that you're missing **Port Forwarding**?  Also, I **highly** recommend you go ahead and get HTTPS working on your LAN and solve that problem BEFORE opening ownCloud up to the Internet.

Comment: I did the port forwarding since the begining. It's ok, I configure the https before set up the static ip. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as a solution :D  Best of luck!

Comment: Well, let me be more precise, as @steeldriver asked. My IP Address is 189.6.17.141 (www.whatismyip.com). The ifconfig command returns as follows:

Comment: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:81:cf:af  
          inet addr:192.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baae:edff:fe81:cfaf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1479 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3
          TX packets:1436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:933481 (933.4 KB)  TX bytes:276224 (276.2 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:83023 (83.0 KB)  TX bytes:83023 (83.0 KB)

Comment: wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:e2:30:88:e7:85  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Comment: Now I tried the graphical interface: system settings, network, wired, options

Comment: Then I choosed IPv4 Settings, method = manual and address = 192.168.0.12, netmask = 255.255.255.0 and gateway 192.168.0.1. Saved the configuration

Comment: After that, I restarted Ubuntu and the messages I see when I tried to browse the internet was...

Comment: This webpage is not available

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
ReloadHide details
The server at intranet can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

Comment: I will be glad if you could help me @earthmelon

Comment: and @steeldriver

Comment: We'll have to turn this into a chat tomorrow and figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Good! I will be available today at 8.30pm here in Brazil = GMT-3. Is it ok to you? I can't start a chat because I have low reputation.

Comment: almost there... I configured wired network connection at the graphical interface with ipv4 settings like this: address 192.168.0.12, netmask 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.0.1 and now I included DNS servers 189.6.0.79, 189.6.0.74 and search domais 127.0.0.1. Now, after reboot, the internet works. But, if I type http://189.6.17.141:80 from other computer outside my network nothing happens... where is my mistake? I set the port forward to 192.168.0.12 star port 80 end port 80.